# Rails 5 - Custom validation from StripeError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, ruby-on-rails-5, activemodel

I have a service that is working with the Stripe API. I have this handler for a subscription that fails to create.

```
    rescue Stripe::StripeError => e
        subscription.errors[:base] << e.message
    end
```

However, I'm not quite sure how to create a validation on the model with that message. Right now, I save the subscription and then try to redirect back to the form if errors exist. But, it seems `.save` clears the errors, so I'm unable to perform the redirect.

It appears that adding a custom validation here is the right way to handle this.

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of validation you're looking for, but if you don't want instances that throw stripe errors to be saved, try adding `throw(:abort)` in your rescue block (after adding the error).

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 5 you have to explicitly throw abort to halt the callback chain. Add `throw(:abort)` in your rescue block to prevent instances that raise `Stripe::StripeError` from being saved.

```
rescue Stripe::StripeError => e
    subscription.errors[:base] << e.message
    throw(:abort)
end
```